# how to pass dynamic mongodump --query inside a sh file while calling from java

Tags: java, mongodb, shell, mongodump

I have a Java code that code that calls a bash file along with arguments like:

```
String query="'{\"regionID\" : \"2\"}'";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/query/sample.sh", database, 
        collection, query, username, password, host, port);
Process p=pb.start();
```

My `sample.sh` file will look like

```
mongodump --host $6 --port $7 --db=$1 --collection=$2 -q $3 --out /query/backup/ --username $4 --password $5 --authenticationDatabase admin
```

When I try to run the mongodump the query fails but without the `-q` parameter it works fine.

Comment: Why do you need a shell script? Can you not just contruct the command directly in your Java Code?

Comment: try to quote "$3". My recent project [mongodbdump-java-wrapper](https://github.com/boly38/mongodbdump-java-wrapper) could maybe help you

Comment: @boly38 it worked!! Thanks !!. but what is the reason for the double quotes anyway?

Comment: cool. Maybe you have some spaces in your $3 and mongodump take some part of your query as unknown extra arguments ? I agree that this is so strange because this is the purpose of process builder constructor (separate each command args); but as you wrap it with an extra shell script.. that maybe the reason.